# Python - loading Module in a Python Webserver

Tags: python, windows, module, webserver

im trying to get Python to load a module depening on what page is requested from a browser, I have it working if the .py file is in the root of the script, but cant seem to get it working if its in a subdirectory.

html files work everywhere, Id appreciate it if someone could help me get the python files to work aswell from any directory.

im running Python 2.7 on win 7 64bit SP1

```
import string,cgi,time
from os import curdir, sep
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import os
import mimetypes

#import pri
port = 888
host = "0.0.0.0"

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

def do_GET(self):
    try:
        #RequestedURL = self.path
        mimeType = mimetypes.guess_type(self.path)[0]
        fileType = mimetypes.guess_extension(mimeType)
        infoList = [mimeType, fileType]

        if infoList[1] != ".py":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', mimeType)
            self.end_headers()
            f = open(curdir + sep + self.path, "rb")
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            f.close()
            return

        if fileType == ".py":
            pythonFilename = self.path.lstrip("/")
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            pyname = pythonFilename.replace("/", ".")[:-3]
            print pythonFilename
            print pyname
            temp1 = pyname.split(".")
            temp2 = temp1[-1]
            print temp2
            module = __import__(root.index)
            self.wfile.write(module.root.index.do_work())
            #module = __import__("test.index")
            #self.wfile.write( module.index.do_work())
            return

        return

    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)


def do_POST(self):
    global rootnode
    try:
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
        if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
            query=cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
        self.send_response(301)

        self.end_headers()
        upfilecontent = query.get('upfile')
        print "filecontent", upfilecontent[0]
        self.wfile.write("<HTML>POST OK.<BR><BR>");
        self.wfile.write(upfilecontent[0]);

    except :
        pass

def main():
try:
    server = HTTPServer((host, port), MyHandler)
    print 'started httpserver:'
    print  ("Host: "  + (host))
    print  ("Port: "  + str(port))

    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down server'
    server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to make sure the sub-directory has a file named

```
__init__.py
```

in it. This file can be blank, but you won't be able to do imports without it. Then, you should know that if you're importing from a sub-directory, you'll have to include something like

```
module = __import__("subdirectory.jack2")
```

That is, you'll need to include the name of the sub-directory the module is stored in when importing the module.

If you want to import from a directory that is not a sub-directory of whatever directory you're working in, you'll have to make sure that it is included in the python path. You can modify the path by setting `sys.path` simply by importing the `sys` module, and appending a new path to wherever your modules are stored:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("full/path/to/directory/to/import/from")
```

**Edit** in response to the comments:

When using the [builtin function `__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__), it is important to realize that it returns the top-level module, not the one that you'd like to import. So, if you want to access the module you just imported, you'll need to do something like this:

```
module = __import__("mymodule")
result = module.mymodule.myfunction()
```

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)

Comment: What was the actual error? That's just the location of the error.

Comment: self.wfile.write( module.do_work())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'do_work'

Comment: I have a folder called "test" and here is a bit of the code that I got from you module = __import__("test.index")
                self.wfile.write( module.do_work())

Comment: inside the "test" folder is index.py nad __init__.py. index has :print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")



def do_work():
    return "Hello World! this is index.py in test"

Comment: It's no problem, it's just the more information you can give us, the more we can help. Try `module.index.do_work()`. Also, since you mentioned that you're new here, I'd like to point out that it's good Stackoverflow etiquette to "accept" an answer to your question if there's one that's useful to you. I noticed you've only done so for 36% of your questions. You might want to go back and accept a few answers on old questions.

Comment: Accepting answers has three main benefits: 1) It rewards the person who took their time to answer your questions. 2) It gives you some reputation. 3) It lets future views of the question know which answer helped you.

Comment: It works, thanks so much! but how would I use "index" as a variable: self.wfile.write(module.index.do_work()) because this works if there is a index.py file in a subdirectory, but not it the root, if I load an index.py file in the root, only this: self.wfile.write(module.do_work()) works